# PHP script output through javascript on webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, powershell

I am trying to build a webpage with a navbar menu and submenu, On click it runs a function in the index.html and calls an ajax function which calls a php script. The php script in turn calls a windows batch file that calls a powershell script.

I am trying to design it such that after I click on the submenu item, the ajax function calls the php script and runs the powershell script. I also want some sort of feedback from the webpage after I click the submenu item to display that it is busy/loading or working on the request, then followed by the result of the php script after it finishes processing. All this while I still have the navbar on and the submenu on top intact.

My problems are,

1. I am getting an pop up alert window, which I think is because of alert(result) in my t1 () ajax function. How can I make it a webpage display?

2.I am not getting any output from the php script that calls the powershell script at the end.

Any help appreciated!

My index.html is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
top: 0;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -1px;
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
}
ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
<div class="container-fluid">


        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VMware VC Reports</a>
        </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vcenters<span class=caret></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">San Jose Vcenter<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" onclick="t1()">ESX Info</a></li>
        </li>
        </ul>

        </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
                </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
$(this).next('ul').toggle();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<script>
function t1 () {
  $.ajax({
    url:"t1.php",
    type: "POST",
    success:function(result){
     alert(result);
   }
 });
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

My t1.php is below.

```
 <?php
 echo "Loading...";
 system("t1.bat");
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=t1.html" />';
 exit;
 ?>
```

My t1.html is below. It has almost all of the index.html and this part added at the bottom

ti.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "t1.txt";
iframe.width = "20000";
iframe.height = "20000";
iframe.frameBorder = "0";
iframe.scrolling = "no";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of alerting the php coming from php append it to a html div.

```
success:function(result){
$('#anydiv').html(result); 
}
```

Please explain this more: "I am not getting any output from the php script that calls the powershell script at the end."

Comment: The php script <?php echo "Loading..."; system("t1.bat"); echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=t1.html" />'; exit; ?> Calls the batch file t1.bat....which is like this Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\xampp\htdocs\view\test\t1.ps1 > "C:\xampp\htdocs\view\test\t1.txt"....It's calling a powershell script...I am not getting any output from this powershell script back to the webpage.

Comment: $('#anydiv').html(result); any div name in index.html or somewhere else?

Comment: Well sure, because `> "C:\xampp\htdocs\view\test\t1.txt"` is redirecting the output of the PowerShell script to the file t1.txt

Comment: I removed the redirection completely, still a blank page.